# Saving graph produced in MATLAB maximized to fullscreen

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am producing graphs in MATLAB using the following command `saveas(gcf, 'save.jpg'])`. However the image that is saved is small. I would like to maximize the graph produced and save the maximized graph. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have looked for this solution for a very a long time, and believe I have found it. The run-time requirements to save the maximized graph seem to be larger than normal because the resolution and image size must be transformed... just something to be aware of.

```
figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
set(gcf, 'PaperPositionMode', 'auto');
```

the first command maximizes the image on your screen, and the second command prepares it to be saved at that size and resolution.